# Jquery accessing function

Tags: jquery, function, recursion

In the function below i am calling on page load, this function is called.  I am very new to jquery and Im wondering how to call the same function inside of this function.  Comments have been inserted to indicate where I need to put the call to the same function to recreate the click triggers.

```
_loadfolder: function () {
    $("#title a").each(
        function (intIndex) {
            $(this).bind(
                "click",
                function () {

                    var stop = intIndex;
                    var temp = '';
                    var directory = '';
                    var item = '';
                    var newlink = '';
                    var folders = '';

                    $("#title a").each(
                        function (intIndex) {
                            item = $(this).text();

                            temp = temp + item;
                            folders = folders + "<a id='item'>" + item + "</a>";
                            if (intIndex == stop) {
                                directory = temp;
                                newlink = folders;
                            }
                        }
                    );

                    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = newlink;

                    $(".template-download").remove();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/' + directory,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        //context: document.body
                        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
                    }).always(function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
                    }).done(function (result) {
                        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {
                                result: result
                            });
                    });
                    console.log($that);
                    //LOAD SAME FUNCTION HERE TO APPLY CLICK TRIGGERS BACK DUE TO INNERHTML REMOVING THEM        
                }
            );
        }
    );
},
```

Comment: If the intention is to rebind the event handlers when the content is replaced (and the previous elements are destroyed), look in to event delegation instead. There's a section on it in the documentation for the `.on()` function.

Comment: Im just trying to reload the function to execute the function code. there might be another way rather than overwriting the html